Is it possible to set up different first factor authentication method on ADFS based on group membership?
I am new in the security environment and I am still learning, I am trying setting up MFA on ADFS and wondering if it's possible to set a configuration like this one:
The normal user just logs with Windows authentication when they connect from the intranet.
The admin user from the intranet are required to log in with MFA, and I want the first factor to be a software key (I've already integrated this method in ADFS), then, as a second factor they should be asked for a forms authentication.
From the extranet everyone should be prompted with MFA.
From the extranet I haven't got any problem because the only primary authenication method that I set up is the software key provider and the only additional method is forms auth.
The problem occurs when I log in with an adminitrative account from the intranet, because as a first factor it triggers Windows authentication and then forms.I was wondering if it is possible to make the software key provider as first authentication method just for the admin gruop and have normal Windows auth for the user group.
I tried to search online documentation but didn't find anything at all, maybe someone got the same problem.
